# Get smooth zoom-in and zoom-out in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21 and displaying zoom slider using

```
    mapOptions.zoomControl = true;
    mapOptions.zoomControlOptions= {
       style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    };
```

Every thing work as expected. The only thing which does not look so great is the `zoom-in and zoom-out using slider` . Its not very smooth and it seems that I can zoom-in/zoom-out by discrete zoom levels and not continuous. But I can see that [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,4.88z) has a zoom slider which works in very smooth and continuous manner. How can I get the same effect in my application ?

Comment: The zoom  step is the same.

Comment: When you zoomi-in or zoom-out using '+' / '-' buttons then zoom step is same, but when you change zoom though slider then its not same.

Answer (score 0):

Google maps work only with **finite zoom level**.

The zoom level is an integer and is directly related to the maps tile showed ..

alias for each zoom level the map tiles retrivied by google maps are determinated by a direct relation for the zoom level and the earth surface mapping.

THe only difference with the slide is the aspect and the fact you can change zoom level directly moving the slider..

Comment: So, there is no way I can get the zoom effects as https://www.google.com/maps/@37.0625,-95.677068,4.5z ?

Comment: its not only the smooth effect, Google maps can also zoom-in/out in more finer zoom steps than maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21